# pattern matching with same variable

Tags: pattern-matching, sml

I have a doubt about the pattern matching in SML. In the book "Programming Language Pragmatics (Second edition)" I read that in SML when you use the pattern matching in a function, the same variable can not appear more than once. The explanation is that pattern matching is used to check if the function can be found in a defined pattern, and not to check if variables are in relation to each others. But it has confused me: why something like this could not be implemented? 
Here is an example:

```
fun Eq nil = false
| Eq (e) = false
| Eq x::x::resto = true //Error
| Eq x::y::resto = false
```

This snippet of code check if the first two elements of a list are equal.
So, why the third line of the code is wrong? Thank you.

Comment: It can be implemented, but it's not in SML (for reasons I'm not aware of). There are languages that allow what you want, for example Erlang. https://gist.github.com/igstan/ac1d10e6d1b575278fd6e2a3b65ce437

Answer (score 2):

Pattern matching only compares compile-time constants and does simple variable assignment otherwise. You can't do a variable comparison via pattern matching. You need to remove the third line and extend the 4th line to

```
Eq x::y::resto = x = y
```

Pattern matching also happens in order. Since `Eq e` actually matches everything, it should be your final clause.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. instead of Eq e, it should have been Eq [e].